# Super compact piston door with button and pressure plate

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Is there a super compact design (or what's the most compact design) for a piston door which should have a button on one side like this:

[image]

and a pressure plate on the other side:

[image]

?

I have tried a lot of configuration and still trying but I can't get it.
Any idea?

PS: If 2 buttons would make it more compact than I can go for it. I need to use it for a house so I need it to be the more compact that I can get. Consider that I need that house to have flat walls this means that if the piston wiring takes horizontally 3 blocks then I need to make 2 3 block spaced walls. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're willing to put the button on the bottom block, this isn't too hard. Try something like this:

[image]

Here's another shot from the top:

[image]

And here's one from the back:

[image]

When either the button is pressed or someone stands on the pressure plate, the door will open.

If you want the button to be at eye level, you can make a minor modification, as suggested in the comments:

[image]

This will allow you to move the button up one block, at the cost of two repeaters. Keep in mind that this will add a (very) small delay to the circuit, but considering it's a button, this might even be an advantage.

Comment: For the cost of 2 repeaters, you can have the button at eye level.  First repeater is to prevent the lower piston from receiving power when the button is presses, the second is to prevent a super fast clock from forming at the back.

Comment: @MBraedley, I'm not sure I understood. Could you make a screenshot please?

Comment: @Jefrey: I would if I were home right now.  Essentially you raise the wood planks block up one, and have the repeaters carry the power out of that block at the same level.  There is of course delay that gets added to the door opening, but that's not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: @Jeffrey I've edited my post to reflect MBraedley's suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can remove the repeater between the other repeater and the redstone dust and put a block in its place if using 2 repeaters isn't an option for him

Comment: @leaf68 He specifically states that he needs a compact design. This is compact.

Comment: @JakeKing It wouldn't change the size at all, all you'd be doing is replacing a repeater with a block...

Comment: @leaf68 Oooh, I see what you're saying now. Sorry about that. Yes, that's probably a good idea.

Comment: At the last design using 2 repeators, can't you replace the last repeater with a normal block?

Answer (score 3):

I made my own design and it fits completely between a 3 wide wall.

**Outside of your house, without wall.**
[image]

[image]

**Inside of your house, without wall.**
[image]

[image]

[image]

**Outside of your house, *with* wall, and door closed.**
[image]

**Inside of your house, with wall, and door closed**
[image]

**Inside of your house with wall, and *door open*** (there is an item on the wood pressure plate)
[image]

Hope this helps, it fits completely inside a 3 wide wall.

Answer (score 2):

This is a piston door that I know how to make. It's fairly compact. It takes a 4-wide by 3-deep by 6-tall space half of the door for a one-way door, so a two-way, 3x2 piston door takes up a total space of 8x5x6.

[image: 2x3 piston door and wiring]

Answer (score 0):

I got a VERY COMPACT,HIDDEN,2x2 door of any block of your choice.Here's a few screenshots. You can make it 2x1 if you really want,just delete a side.
[image: The Redstone]

[image: Piston Placement]

[image: Redstone/lever]

[image: Closed=Unnoticable..... The Big dirt blob on the right is nothing,i just put it there so it looks like natural generation.]